# How to use the contents of a Vue js component as are initially loaded and then bind them to a variable

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

We are looking to get the contents from the html (for example using a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) ) but we *later* (after mounting) want to bind this to a variable as one would do with a v-html.

In other words we want on initialization to have the contents being loaded as they appear in the slot and later this entire piece of content to be controlled by a binding variable like v-html (because it will be html content).

How to achieve this? without following any ugly solutions such as needing to pass the entire initial html content inside v-html attribute!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<template>
  <custom-component>
    <div v-if="html_variable" v-html="html_variable"></div>
    <template v-else>
     <!-- default content here -->
    </template>
  </custom-component>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  data()
  {
    return {html_variable: null};
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How using `v-html` is ugly? Anyway just use a non-visible element to define your initial html. a `<script ref="initHTML" type="text/html"> ... </script>` might be a good option.

Define a data entry that should hold your HTML init:

```
data () {
   return {
       dHTML: '',
   }
},
```

On `created()` update your initial html state using the ref

```
created() {
    this.dHTML = this.$refs.initHTML.innerHTML;
},
```

Now you can have a pretty `v-html="dHTML"`